# How does the phpMyAdmin export feature work?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

If I were to want to create a PHP function that does the same thing as the Export tab in phpMyAdmin, how could I do it? I don't know if there is a MySQL function that does this or if phpMyAdmin just builds the export file (in SQL that is) manually. Without shell access. Just using PHP.

I tried the documentation for [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html), but that seemed to require using the shell. I'm not quite sure what that even is -- maybe my question is: how do you use shell?

My silly idea is to allow non-technical users to build a site on one server (say a localhost) using MySQL then export the site, database and all, to another server (eg. a remote server).

I think I'm pretty clear on the Import process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the phpMyAdmin source code (an advantage of open-source software). Check the export.php script and the supporting functions in the libraries/export/sql.php script file.

In summary, what phpMyAdmin does is:

- get a list of the tables in the given database (SHOW TABLES FROM...),
- get the create query for each table (SHOW CREATE TABLE...),
- parse it and extract column definitions from it,
- get all data (SELECT * FROM...)
- build a query according to column data.

I've written similar code for my own apps (for backup purposes, when the GPL license of phpMyAdmin doesn't allow me to use it), however I use DESCRIBE to get column definitions. I think they rather parse the SHOW CREATE TABLE output because contains more information than DESCRIBE output.

This way to generate SQL sentences requires a bit of care to handle the escaping but it allows for some flexibility, as you can convert types, filter or sanitize data, etc. It is also a lot slower than using a tool like mysqldump and you should take care of not consuming all available memory (write soon, write often, don't keep everything in memory).

If you will implement a migration process (from server to server) maybe it would be easier to do it with some shell scripting and calling mysqldump directly, unless you will do everything with PHP.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Yeah, I think, because I know php I'd want to do everything in PHP. It's WordPress-like CMS programming. I figured phpMyAdmin runs a series of steps, but I had to ask before spending a lot of time doing it from scratch. I'm all about reinventing wheel to waste away lots of good Saturdays.

Comment: Great question.  I learnt something crazy today.  I can't understand why they don't offer mysqldump like functionality over the database connection.  Why separate the dumping to another program?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ I have wondered the same thing everytime I have to write code to do it. That would be very useful indeed. I don't know any RDBMS that do it, they have SQL instructions to dump locally (like SELECT... INTO OUTFILE or BACKUP DATABASE) or command-line tools or GUI tools, but nothing to do it thru the network from your own application.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin never use the `mysqldump` binary from mysql ?

Comment: into `PMA\libraries\classes\Plugins\Export\ExportSql.php` you will find `public function exportData()`...