# How can I pull data from a MySQL with millions of rows remotely efficiently? (mysqldump is not an option)

Tags: mysql

I have a remote database table that I need to pull the data from. Because I have no control over the remote database, other than read access, I can't update indices to make the queries faster.

**mysqldump is not an option.**

Methods I've tried so far:

- Pagination (using limit and offset); basically operating like a cursor

Issues that I'm running into:

- High CPU load on the database due to being unable to set new indices
- Seems to be unreliable due to long query times (20+ seconds per query)

Any advice would he greatly appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: What technology? What language?

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about dumping the data out like a cache/backup, then you can follow up on @hiropon's answer.

On the other hand, if the purpose of the query is so that the data you dumped can interact with your other tables on your server (eg: inner join), then you may consider using federated table.

Answer (score 0):

hiropon posted a viable solution which is a php port of mysqldump:

[Backup database(s) using query without using mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167769/backup-databases-using-query-without-using-mysqldump)