# Code igniter mysql backup fails with large databases -- any alternatives besides mysqldump?

Tags: php, mysql

I know that mysqldump will always work, but my users are not technically inclined enough to use it. Which is why `$backup =& $this->dbutil->backup();` has been so great! As the database grows it size the backup will eventually fail. PHPMYAdmin can seem to do larger databases than codeiniter's backup solution.

I have been looking all over for a simple and free solution that can at least do 30 mb databases. I would be grateful for any solutions that you may have come across

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388546/how-does-phpmyadmin-export-work if you're looking to reproduce what phpMyAdmin does.

Answer (score 1):

I've had much luck using this little guy: http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

Make sure you read over the notes page: http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/usage/ to double check this will work for your solution.

Comment: This looks like with a little work I can get this to work for me. Thanks

Comment: I dug into it more and there are a few problems for my scenario. The main problem is it needs write permissions. I need to be able to do it without write permissions and have it return a string. It doesn't need  to work with really large databases, but maybe 10-20mb as phpMyAdmin supports.